# How to Scrape a Website Using Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: xpath, screen-scraping

I have this website https://gpfo.memberclicks.net//index.php?option=com_community&view=profile&userid=23705974 and I am trying to extract the href link behind 'View' under 'Full Profile'.

I'd like to know how to scrape this. I tried `//dl[1]/dd[contains(a/text(),'View')]/@href` but it didn't return any data.

I'd also like to get an expert opinion on what the most efficient way to scrape websites is: is it better to directly run importXML from Google Docs or is there a better way to doing it using Scripts?

Answer (score 1):

You try to query for the `<dd>`'s `@href` tag (which is not present). Try

```
//dd/a[. = 'View']/@href
```

instead. Or, staying closer to your original expression:

```
//dl[1]/dd/a[contains(text(),'View')]/@href
```

> Is it better to directly run importXML from Google Docs or is there a better way to doing it using Scripts?

Depends on how complex things will get. If you just want to read some tabular data, you're probably better off with plain Spreadsheets; if it is more complicated writing your own script might be reasonable.